# Cálculo com número decimais PHP

Tags: php

Estou fazendo uma consulta, que obtém 2 valores do banco de dados.
Ele retorna os valores corretamento com virgula. Mas quando é feita a multiplicação, não está contando as casas decimais.

```
foreach ($compra['CompraItem'] as $valores) {                       
    $cotacao = $modeloMoedaCotacao->find('first', array('conditions'=>array(
        'MoedaCotacao.moeda_id' => $valores['moeda_id'],
        'MoedaCotacao.data' => date("Y-m-d"),
    ), array(
        'limit' => 1,
    )));
    echo $cotacao = FloatFromSQL($cotacao['MoedaCotacao']['cotacao']);
    echo '<br />';                                                
    echo $valor = FloatFromSQL($valores['valor']);
    echo '<br />';                                                
    $valorTotal = $valor * $cotacao;
    echo $valorTotal;
    echo '<br />';                                                
}
```

Retorno:

5,14000
1980,00
= multiplicação retorna sem usar a casa decimal >> 9900

3,23000
160,00
= multiplicação retorna sem usar a casa decimal >>480

5,14000
70,00
= multiplicação retorna sem usar a casa decimal >>350

Comment: Qual é o SGBD por trás e, mais importante, sabe dizer o tipo de dados que está sendo usado pra armazenar esses números?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você vai trabalhar com cálculos frequentemente aconselho utilizar uma função que possa formatar estes valores.

**Exemplo:**

```
function valor_func($aValor, $aTipo, $a_dec = 2) { // valores com mascara e sem mascara
   switch ($aTipo):
      case 'C':// com mascara
         $valor = number_format(round($aValor, $a_dec), $a_dec, ',', '.');
         break;

      case 'S':// sem mascara
         $valor = str_replace(',', '.', str_replace('.', '', $aValor));
         break;

      case 'A':// arrendonda
         $valor = round($aValor, $a_dec);
         break;
      case 'D':// Decimais sem arredonda,sem mascara
         $posPonto = strpos($aValor, '.');
         if ($posPonto > 0):
            $valor = substr($aValor, 0, $posPonto) . '.' . substr($aValor, $posPonto + 1, $a_dec);
         else:
            $valor = $aValor;
         endif;
         break;
   endswitch;
   return $valor;
}
```

para mostrar os valores para o usuario use o tipo `'C'` e para calcular utilize o tipo `'S'` exemplo :

```
$a = "5,14000"; // com mascara

echo valor_func($a,'S');// 5.14000 sem mascara
echo valor_func($a,'C');// 5,14000 com mascara
```

Comment: evite esse tipo de função multiuso. Outra coisa que o number_format (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.number-format.php) também ajudaria a formatar o número

Comment: gostaria que me explicasse o "evite função multiuso",  number_format é utilizado na função descrita acima, esta função além de agregar rotinas de formatações para números ela facilita a utilização da mesma.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que nós utilizamos a vírgula como separador decimal `,` no PHP o separador decimal é o ponto `.`

Dito isso você tem N formas de resolver seu problema, desde trazer esses números formatados com ponto `.` do seu banco de dados ou converter no PHP

```
<?php
$a = "5,14000";
$b = "1980,00";

$a = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $a));
$b = floatval(str_replace(",", ".", $b));

var_dump($a*$b);
```

---

Se você estiver utilizando o PHP na versão maior que o 5.3 e ter o `intl` instalado pode usar o [NumberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/numberformatter.parse.php).

Comment: Corretamente, eu só precisava convertê-los para "." pois o php só faz multiplicação com ".". Muito obrigado.

Comment: O correto é dizer que na matemática, não no PHP, o separador decimal é o ponto. A vírgula, usa-se no Brasil e outros diversos países por mal habito mesmo e com o tempo virou costume.